# Tensorflow Deeplab image colormap removal confusion

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

In this following code, I only see, an image is read and written again. But **how do the image pixel values get changed so drastically?** Apparently, converting the PIL image object to `numpy` array causes this but don't know why. I have read the doc for PIL images but didn't see any reasonable explanation for this to happen.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def _remove_colormap(filename):
  return np.array(Image.open(filename))


def _save_annotation(annotation, filename):
  pil_image = Image.fromarray(annotation.astype(dtype=np.uint8))
  pil_image.save(filename)


def main():
  raw_annotation = _remove_colormap('2007_000032.png')
  _save_annotation(raw_annotation, '2007_000032_output.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Input image is,

[image: Input image]

Here is the output,

[image: Output image]

**Note:** The value at the red area in the input image is [128,0,0] and in the output image it's [1,1,1].

The actual source of the code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/remove_gt_colormap.py).

**Edit**:
As @taras made it clear in his comment,

> Basically, palette is a list of 3 * 256 values in form 256 red values,
>   256 green values and 256 blue values. Your pil_image is an array of
>   greyscale pixels each taking a single value in 0..255 range. When
>   using 'P' mode the pixel value k is mapped to a color (pallette[k],
>   palette[256 + k], palette[2*256 + k]). When using 'L' mode the color
>   is simply k or (k, k, k) in RGB

The segmentation image annotations use a unique color for each object type. So we don't need the actual color palette for the visualization, we get rid of the unnecessary color palette.

Comment: It has something to do with 'P' (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette) mode. When you write your output image this information is lost and you get greyscale image instead.

Comment: I have explained it quite thoroughly here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677796/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Use PIL to load png file gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676447/python-use-pil-to-load-png-file-gives-strange-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check of the opened image mode with

```
Image.open(filename).mode
```

shows the input file is opened with `'P'` mode 
which stands for

> 8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette

So, when you generate image with `Image.fromarray` the palette is simply lost
and you are left with a greyscale image in `'L'` mode.

You simply need to provide the palette info when creating the output array.

The palette can be extracted with `Image.getpalette()`:

```
def _remove_colormap(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    palette = img.getpalette()
    return np.array(img), palette
```

Once you created your `pil_image` you can set the palette back with `Image.putpalette(palette)`

```
def _save_annotation(annotation, palette, filename):
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(annotation.astype(dtype=np.uint8))
    pil_image.putpalette(palette)
    pil_image.save(filename)
```

And your `main` changed accordingly:

```
def main():
    raw_annotation, palette = _remove_colormap('SqSbn.png')
    _save_annotation(raw_annotation, palette, '2007_000032_output.png')
```

**Edit:**

`palette` is a list of 3 * 256 values in the following form:
256 red values, 256 green values and 256 blue values.

`pil_image` is an array of greyscale pixels each taking a single value in 0..255 range. When using `'P'` mode the pixel value `k` is mapped to an RGB color `(pallette[k], palette[256 + k], palette[2*256 + k])`. When using 'L' mode the color is simply `k` or `(k, k, k)` in RGB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I don't want to change the code. I just want to know how the values are changed here. Does it follow any defined rule to convert the palette? I mean how [128,0,0] turns into [1,1,1]

Comment: Basically, palette is a list of 3 * 256 values in form 256 red values, 256 green values and 256 blue values. Your `pil_image` is an array of greyscale pixels each taking a single value in 0..255 range. When using `'P'` mode the pixel value `k` is mapped to a color `(pallette[k], palette[256 + k], palette[2*256 + k])`. When using `'L'` mode the color is simply `k` or `(k, k, k)` in RGB.

Comment: I think in `P` mode, the pixel value `k` is mapped to color `(pallette[3*k], palette[3*k+1], palette[3*k+2])` instead of `(pallette[k], palette[256 + k], palette[2*256 + k])`

Reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving

Answer (score 1):

Mode conversion is missing in `_remove_colormap(filename)`. As it's defined in the question (and the answer from @taras), `remove_colormap` converts a PIL image into a numpy array. `_save_annotation()` further converts the numpy array into a PIL image. RGB image is saved as such. `convert('L')` should be used for converting to grayscale. Modified function definition is as under:

```
def _remove_colormap(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
    palette = img.getpalette()
    print("palette: ", type(palette))
    return np.array(img), palette
```